# which Distribution of Linux is best suited for Nutch-Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, nutch

we are Trying to figure out which Distribution of Linux be best suited for the Nutch-Hadoop Integration?.
we are planning to Use Clusters for Crawling  large  contents through Nutch.
Let me Know if You  need more clarification on this question?.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference between any major Linux distribution in this case. But I'd recommend you one that has hadoop packages prepared. I'm using Cloudera's Hadoop distribution on debian and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop and hbase packages will be in the next Debian Stable version:

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hadoop